After MIG is enabled, how do I configure gres.conf for slurm
When the MIG is disabled, you can specify a graphics card device by running /dev/nvidia[0-7], but after the MIG device is enabled, the MIG device cannot be found.
How to configure？
gres.conf:
#AutoDetect=nvml
NodeName=ubuntu-DeepLearning-4896[001,005,009,013,017,021,025,029,033,037,041,045]  Name=gpu File=/dev/nvidia[0-7]
